# javafx tablecolumn cell change

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, tablecolumn

I am looking to set the cell column to receive an object circle in replacement of the value that is coming from a database in an observableList. Values are populated in that column that mirror the other column(lets say col A and B (left to right) - they basically contain the same information except- I wanted col B to change to represent the circle object.Here is my code so far, please advise if you have suggestions.

```
status.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, Circle>, ObservableValue<Circle>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Circle> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, Circle> param) {


        String c = (String) param.getValue().get(2); //getting all data in column 2 of the row
        System.out.println(c);

        switch(c){

            case "High":        
                circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                healthstatus.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");            
                break;

            case "Medium":
                circle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                healthstatus.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");           
                break;

            case "Low":
                circle.setFill(Color.RED);
                healthstatus.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");           
                break;

            default:
                circle.setFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
            }   
        return new SimpleObjectProperty(circle);                        
    }            
});
```

I prefer to continue with the code I have without having to create a class in response to setting the value.

I've attached a picture to show my result so far.

thanks in advance!
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezDQI.png)

Comment: If the two columns contain the same information, but differ in how they display it, use the same `cellValueFactory` for both. Use a different `cellFactory` to change how the data are displayed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **Update**

As @kleopatra pointed out some issues and suggestions from the previous answer, I have updated the answer accordingly.

**CircleCell**

Customized TableCell for Circle rendering

```
public class CircleCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (isSafe(item, empty)) {
            CellData data = CellData.cellData(item);
            Circle circle = new Circle(6);
            circle.setFill(data.getColor());
            setGraphic(circle);
        }
    }

    private boolean isSafe(String item, boolean empty) {
        return !empty && Objects.nonNull(item);
    }
}
```

**CellData**

Holds color based on cell data.

```
public enum CellData {

    HIGH("High", Color.GREEN),
    MEDIUM("Medium", Color.YELLOW),
    LOW("Low", Color.RED),
    NONE("None", Color.BLUEVIOLET);

    private String data;
    private Color color;

    CellData(String data, Color color) {
        this.data = data;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public static CellData cellData(String data) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                    .filter(e -> e.data.equals(data))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(NONE);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

**Set Factory**

Set cell-factory with the customized CircleCell.

```
status.setCellFactory(column -> new CircleCell());
```

> **Simple Demo**

```
public class CustomCellDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(getTable());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TableView<Person> getTable() {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(statusColumn());
        table.setItems(getItems());
        return table;
    }

    private TableColumn<Person, String> statusColumn() {
        TableColumn<Person, String> status = new TableColumn<>();
        status.setCellFactory(col -> new CircleCell());
        status.setGraphic(new Label("Status"));
        status.setStyle("-fx-alignment:center");
        status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Status"));
        status.setMinWidth(199);
        return status;
    }

    private ObservableList<Person> getItems() {
        ObservableList<Person> detail = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        detail.add(new Person("Medium"));
        detail.add(new Person("Low"));
        detail.add(new Person("High"));
        detail.add(new Person(""));
        detail.add(new Person(null));
        return detail;
    }

    public class Person {
        private SimpleStringProperty status;

        public Person(String status) {
            this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(status);
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status.get();
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(status);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: genius! @ShekkarRaee  - thank you, it worked! ...since I am noob, I will still need to digest the concepts abit more

Comment: do you ever _test_ your snippets? hint: you'll get a NPE if the cell has been re-/used once for an empty cell ...

Comment: @kleopatra I have tested it well and added a demo as well :)

Comment: clean-up missing again ...  *sigh